# example of how to use synonyms in nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

i haven't found a solid example on how to create and use synonyms using Nest for Elasticsearch. if anyone has one it would be helpful.

my attempt looks like this, but i don't know how to apply it to a field.

```
var syn = new SynonymTokenFilter
{
    Synonyms = new [] { "pink, p!nk => pink", "lil, little", "ke$ha, kesha => ke$ha" },     
    IgnoreCase = true,
    Tokenizer = "standard"
};

client.CreateIndex("myindex", i =>
{
    i
        .Analysis(a => a.Analyzers(an => an
            .Add("fullTermCaseInsensitive", fullTermCaseInsensitive)
            )
            .TokenFilters(x => x
                .Add("synonym", syn)
                )
            )
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `fullTermCaseInsensitive` analyzer is custom, you need to add your synonym filter to it:

```cs
var fullTermCaseInsensitive = new CustomAnalyzer()
    {
        .
        .
        .
        Filter = new string[] { "syn" }
    };
```

And upon creating your index, you can add a mapping and apply the `fullTermCaseInsensitive` analyzer to your field(s):

```cs
client.CreateIndex("myindex", c => c
    .Analysis(a => a
        .Analyzers(an => an.Add("fullTermCaseInsensitive", fullTermCaseInsensitive))
        .TokenFilters(tf => tf.Add("syn", syn)))
    .AddMapping<MyType>(m => m
        .Properties(p => p
            .String(s => s.Name(t => t.MyField).Analyzer("fullTermCaseInsensitive")))));
```

Comment: that works! i think i was on the right track anyway... in your opinion, should i create a multifield in order to search using the synonyms (say on the 'artist' field) or should i just use the synonym filter and make it a regular field (not-multifield)?

Comment: also, it looks like i can't replace single characters? for example $, s? it will not index if i use that in my list of synonyms.

Answer (score 3):

it's very simple :)
you will need to define first the Synonym filter the you can use it in your custom Analyzer...where you can add also other type of filters.
Small example :

```
        .Analysis(descriptor => descriptor
            .Analyzers(bases => bases
                .Add("folded_word", new CustomAnalyzer()
                {
                    Filter = new List<string> { "icu_folding", "trim", "synonym" },
                    Tokenizer = "standard"
                }
            )                 
         )
         .TokenFilters(i => i
                     .Add("synonym", new SynonymTokenFilter() 
                     {
                        SynonymsPath="analysis/synonym.txt",
                        Format = "Solr"
                     }
                     )
         )
```

Then you can use the custom analyzer in the mapping part